# Problem for using var in a path Python3 - EOF ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, path, eof

I've got trouble to verify a path who contains variables using "os.path.exists(path)". Which character should be used to put the content of vars in path and then verify the path?

*nb : EOF Error...*

Thanks you.

```
path = (C:\programm\.....\+var1+\+var2+\)
isExist = os.path.exists(path)
if (isExist == false):
    os.mkdirs(path)
else:
    print (" ")
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
# change \ to \\
path = ("C:\\programm\\.....\\+var1+\\+var2+\\")
isExist = os.path.exists(path)
# change false to False
if (isExist == False):
    # change os.mkdir to os.makedirs
    os.makedirs(path)
else:
    print (" ")
```

Comment: Using `exists` like that is subject to a race condition, because another process could create the directory in between the two operations. It's more robust to eliminate the `exists` check by putting `mkdir/makedirs` in a `try/except` and catching `FileExistsError`.

Comment: Please add some explanation with your code.

Comment: thought that was not so hard to understand... well thanks

Answer (score 0):

modify value of path variable as,

**path = (C:\programm\.....\+var1+\+var2+\)**

backslash is a escape character in programming languages, so to print backslash, we need to put double backslash(\) in variable value or print statement.

Comment: Just see that we can use a simple slash instead of double backslash and escape var in path with this : " .  Example : path = (C:/.../.../"+var1+"/..../"+var2"/)